# Variable Solidifier Thickness

Tags: modifiers, geometry, geometry-nodes, solidify-modifier

I have a honeycomb style wall and need to make some of the cells a different thickness than others. I have started by using a solidify modifier, to no avail. Is there a way to achieve this look:
[image: Honeycomb Wall]

I have simply added a cylinder with 6 sides, no top or bottom faces. Used a solidify modifier and two array sets to achieve the look, but all the rims still have the same thickness.

Comment: The solidify modifier has a Vertex Group input options which lets you factor the shell depth accordingly to the value. I see you're using Geometry Nodes in your project. Would you mind posting your node tree to make sure the potential answers really fit to your needs ?

Comment: does it have to be geometry nodes or would you also be satisfied with sverchok or animation nodes solution?

Comment: It does not have to be Geometry Nodes, but I suppose it would be better, considering the flexibility it will offer :) I have a solution for achieving the same visual result, but it's very manual work - i.e. create a grid of hexagons with array modifiers, then another array scaled down, then a boolean modifier...you get the drill :D

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it. (...by the way, that goes for all the other questions you've asked here on BSE, which have thankfully been answered by the hardworking folks here) Thank you! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, it is possible, although my "solution" is not very nice, because i use the mesh boolean node which is very slow in geometry nodes.

Basically my idea is this: i build a geometry nodes grid with cylinders with 6 vertices. Then i build another geometry nodes grid with smaller but higher cylinders, which i use a cutter objects for my first grid. By this i can scale (e.g. with proximity node) my cutter instances and so the hexagon will have different thickness.

[image]

Node setup:

[image]

Comment: +1 but your node setup is a bit too simple imho  :((

Comment: I can only do simple things…‍♂️

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much for the input! I will definitely try it out :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you.