# Array Animation On Geometry Nodes Curve Overlapping

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I have a *Geometry Nodes* setup that takes a curve, resamples it, distributes some instances to the points, and then I can offset and keyframe the instances so it looks like an "conveyor belt" style animation.

The problem is that there is a point where 2 instances overlap. Oddly enough, one of the instances doesn't respond at all to the transformation I'm testing on it. I can't get rid of it either.

It would be great if I could get some help here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: besides that your node tree isn't really readable at all...it would be a big help and attract more people if you provide your blend file so we don't have to recreate everything on our own

Comment: and by the way, it would be nice if you could click on the checkmark left of an answer, if the answer helped you like e.g. here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245542/variable-solidifier-thickness

Comment: If you want to create a repeating animation along a curve, then you would have to leave out the first or last point. Think about it: that would be like a portal, because a point can't be at the beginning and the end at the same time, because the beginning and the end are one point. ...it's a loop.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that helped. I was sick and out of commission for some days so apologies for the delay on the check mark. Also sorry about the node tree readability, I was really pressed on time (had 10 mins to make it and post the question). I am way more organized than this normally. Thank you very much again for the help and the learning opportunity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the task could (should) be solved:

[image]
[image]

Instead of moving the curve points themselves, I create a `Mesh Line` here.

When converting this help line with `Mesh to Points` I redefine the positions of the points.

I get the positions by mapping the index into a range of $0$ to $1$, adding this with the `Scene Time` and the math node `Fraction` returns a corresponding value, which is also between $0$ and $1$, but is shifted accordingly.

I get the rotation here directly from the tangents and normals of the sampled curve points.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>