# How to toggle switch using geometry proximity?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create an assembly line/conveyor belt using *Geometry Nodes*, by attaching objects to a curve and following along it.

I want to place an *Empty* or invisible objects along the path, so that when an object pass through that *Empty* it would toggle to a different object using *Switch* node or some sort of proximity sensor, and all objects before the *Empty* wouldn't switch.

But I can't figure out how to use *Geometry Proximity* as toggle for the *Switch* node, and if it's even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node `Switch`, once set to *Geometry*, only accepts a single value and not a [field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html), so unfortunately it cannot be used as you wish.

To solve this task, you don't need the node `Geometry Proximity`, but only the following setup:

[image]

Here I combine several objects with `Geometry to Instance`, which are then selectively chosen when instantiating with `Instance on Points`.

You just have to activate the option *Pick Instance*, and pass an integer value to *Instance Index*.

You can get this value by comparing the position of the points you use for instantiation with the position of an additional object. If the distance is below a certain value, the number $1$ will be used instead of $0$, thus using the second object from the previously created group of instances.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Could you please help me, how to do the same, but along the bezier curve, tried multiple setups and something always breaks

Comment: @Sugrmax Please forgive me, I don't quite understand what you mean. It shouldn't really make a difference whether you use a mesh line or a Bezier curve. Which part exactly is not working? Maybe it would be good if you share the blend file with us.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=orK06gR4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/orK06gR4/)

Comment: @Sugrmax Ah, I see, that's another topic. So you want an additional repeating movement, a kind of loop?

Comment: @Sugrmax To do this, you would first have to convert your Nurbs path to a mesh line, or in some form to a curve that has points evenly spaced. Then you can combine that with [this setup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277710/145249). Or with [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270820/145249).

Comment: You are amazing, thanks a lot for your help!